# url manager restful api in yii2

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2, restful-url

1.how make this url

```
http://localhost/travia-api/backend/web/v1/flight?id=4FR996IN2F829M
```

to this

```
http://localhost/travia-api/backend/web/v1/flight/4FR996IN2F829M
```

this is my config

```
  'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller' => 'flight',

            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>/view',
            '<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
           '<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
           'v1/<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => 'v1/<controller>/<action>',
           'v1/<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>' => 'v1/<controller>/<action>',
           'module/<module:[\w\-]+>/<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
        ],
```

and this is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

2.and when i want to add new pattern i add these line to config

```
extraPatterns[
   'GET search' => 'search'
]
```

after that i have error like these

> Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
>   Setting unknown property: yii\web\UrlRule::GET search

i did a lot but i couldn't found something useful!
**thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

With this rules:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
'<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>/view',
'<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

You only gets digits on the`id` try to get words too:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+\w+>' => '<controller>/view',
'<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>/view',
'<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

Because you want digits and words:

```
http://localhost/travia-api/backend/web/v1/flight/4FR996IN2F829M
```

I dont know how to resolve the second question properly but try this:

```
extraPatterns[
   'GET{id}' => 'search'
]
```

I saw it [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-urlrule.html#$patterns-detail)

**EDIT:**

Change this rules:

```
'v1/<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => 'v1/<controller>/<action>',
'v1/<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>' => 'v1/<controller>/<action>',
```

For this:

```
'v1/flight/<id:[\d+\w+]>' => 'v1/flight/actionName',
'v1/flight/<action:\w+' => 'v1/flight/<action>',
```

And setit as a first rules. Remember to change `actionName`

Comment: will change my response

Comment: it's not a solution ! about #1 ?

Comment: it is, i dont know how to help you in the Q2 u.u'

Comment: i solved that problem with queryparameter like :http://localhost/travia-api/backend/web/v1/flight?id=4FR996IN2F829M  but is is not friendly!